# Making jar files available to the scala REPL

Tags: scala, classpath, read-eval-print-loop, artifact

I can't seem to get this to work, so i have tried what's probably the most straightforward case--ie, retrieve the jar file and into a given directory then start the scala REPL from that directory--still no luck.

I know the jar files are fine and correctly references (eg, i can access them from project directories via eclipse/scala ide)

I also know that my import statements (one is shown below) are valid.

```
cd ~/my_scala_jars
```

*retrieve the artifact from the maven repo*

```
wget -q -nd -np -r \
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.12.0-M1/7.1.2/scalaz-core_2.12.0-M1-7.1.2.jar
```

*start the scala REPL and add the jar to the REPL classpath:*

```
scala -cp scalaz-core_2.12.0-M1-7.1.2.jar

scala> import scalaz.stream.io
<console>:7: error: object stream is not a member of package scalaz
   import scalaz.stream.io
```

in case it's useful, trying this with different jars (that i downloaded as i showed with scalaz above) will sometimes cause the REPL to throw a *not found* error instead

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._ 
<console>:7: error: not found: value breeze
    import breeze.linalg._
```

it seems to me that the REPL should recognize these jars because the directory has been added to my CLASSPATH, but also because i believe the current directory is also added to the classpath (at least during the REPL session)--and still both fail.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the specific question, but if you create a build.sbt that references the library you want to have available, you can just start a scala REPL with sbt console from the directory with your build.sbt and all will be good. I've got a good few build.sbt files around that I just use for starting REPLs with the libraries I want available.

Comment: @MikeCurry that's how i do it now but what i'm trying to do is in the scala docs (and apparently allows updating the classpath on the fly). In any event, if you make your comment an answer, i'll accept + upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, I added the answer. Sorry it is not more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the jar files are not picked up as I haven't really tried to do that. What I do, and find useful, is to create a number of `build.sbt` files for specific purposes, e.g. for working with a specific suite of libraries at a REPL.

If you do this, and then launch a REPL using the command `sbt console`, from the directory containing the appropriate `build.sbt`, then you can have a console with the libraries you want available on the classpath to that console.

This might not be ideal, but it does work and I find it quite useful.